# AWS EC2 Security Group SSH Access From USA Only

Tags: amazon-ec2

Struggling with Security Groups in AWS. Would like to setup a single SG, which I'd use in all my EC2 instances, to allow SSH traffic (I'd have other SGs for other roles, deployed as appropriate). However, I see no reason to open this SSH group up to the whole world. **What I'd like to do is to restrict access to USA only for now. Is this doable?**

Answer (score 5):

It is doable with [pam_geoip](http://ankh-morp.org/code/pam_geoip/)

In /etc/security/geoip.conf:

```
*           sshd          allow     US
*           sshd          ignore    UNKNOWN
*           sshd          deny      *
```

Comment: OK, thanks. But can't be done in an AWS security group??

Comment: You could download the geoip CSV file, select rows with the US as the country, and use `aws ec2 authorize-security-group-ingress` to allow the associated IPs...

Comment: Mark Wagner, thanks, that does answer the question. Not sure it's a feasible approach, but it's an answer to the actual question, and I asked the question in order to determine the feasibility, so... victory! Much appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

Possible, in theory, but probably not what you want to do.

I could, for example, use a free VPN service to give me an IP address in the USA, even though I'm in London.

What would be a better solution would be a SSH key, disable password-based logins, and consider 2-factor authentication.

I'm confused by why you'd want to allow access to the netblocks for a country as a whole, when it only offers you the thinnest veil of security (through obscurity)

Comment: For now it's not feasible to restrict SSH access to a specific, narrow list of IPs, but I do hope to get there eventually. My idea was to start with "better than nothing" and improve from there.

Comment: Also, we do use keys and pw-based logins are disabled already.

Comment: You might want to look into port knocking. You could allow a small list of known OK ips, and then allow anyone else to use the port knock to get a temporary firewall exception made for that ip.

Comment: My question was pretty straight-forward. It was a valid question, and it represents something I was curious about implementing as a single piece of my overall security regimen. These answers/comments don't have anything to do with AWS security groups, and so, don't really help. Thanks anyway

Comment: @Waldron The answer is "You're *doing it wrong*". Don't expect a site of professionals to help you *do it wrong* - Rather than stomp your feet and say "that isn't what I was asking for" try taking the time to understand why what you want is not a great idea, and then implement one of the *good* solutions offered here or in [Mark's answer](http://serverfault.com/a/499604/32986) instead.

Comment: @voretaq7, not sure you understood my comment or the spirit of my quetison. See response to Mark Wagner in other answer.